# Cant redirect where I want it - laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, frameworks, laravel-routing

When I log in it should redirect me to /spotlight, but it does not. And if you are not logged in and you try to access /spotlight it redirects you to log in.
Any idea why?

http://pastebin.com/ERVAj2eu

Comment: Where do you land once you successfully log in?

Comment: I thought as much :/ Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the auth filter before the route for spotlight is served so this must be checking if the user is logged in and if they are not they are being redirected to the login page.

In the login route you need to change this:

```
return Redirect::intended('/');
```

to this:

```
return Redirect::intended('/spotlight');
```

This should now redirect to the spotlight route after login.

Comment: its not redirecting after login

Comment: Are you being logged in successfully? Whats in the auth function that is being run before the spotlight route is served?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Redirect::route('spotlight');
```

and create that route

```
Route::get("/spotlight", array( "as" => "spotlight", "uses" => "Controller@function");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please re-write your 'login' route as follows. Per your current logic whether authentication is successful or not, you are presented with the 'login' page again; you have to have an `else` clause so that the `login` page is re-loaded **only and only if authentication fails**:

```
Route::post('/login', function()
{
    $credentials = Input::only('username', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return Redirect::intended('/');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
});
```